# How can I iterate over this JSON dictionary correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the League of Legends static data JSON file as follows:

```
url = 'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/champion.json'
```

I want to iterate over all keys in this dictionary and look for the 'key' value in each dictionary key and compare it to a value. I then want to set the dictionary key that the matching 'key' was found in to a variable.

Here is my code so far:

```
import requests

def findChampionName(championID):
    url = 'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/champion.json'
    r = requests.get(url)
    json_obj = r.json()
    data = json_obj['data']
    for champ in data:
        if data[champ]['key'] == str(championID):
            return champ

u = findChampionName(142)
print(u)
```

So far this only yields me a `None` result for `u`.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but it's driving me crazy!

Comment: there is no 142 in this json file, so maybe that's why...

Comment: That was a mistake on my part, but even with a valid number I still get a return of None.

Comment: if you do `for champ in data` then you do not need to do `data[champ]['key']` again. Simply use `champ['key']`

Comment: works for me though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to properly check the type of `data`'s and its contents.

Let's start with this:

```
data = json_obj['data']
```

The `data` here is a `dict`. The [usual way](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) to iterate over a `dict` is using [`.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) to separate the `dict` key and value into a tuple pair:

```
for name, attributes in data.items():
```

Based on the contents of `data`, the key seems to be the champ name (`'Aatrox'`) and the value is another `dict` containing the `champ`'s attributes:

```
{'version': '6.24.1', 
 'id': 'Aatrox', 
 'key': '266', 
 'name': 'Aatrox', 
 'title': 'the Darkin Blade', 
 ...
}
```

Now, I think you are comparing the `key` with the `championID`. So you just need to access the `attributes` `'key'` like this:

```
if attributes['key'] == str(championID):
```

Putting them all together:

```
import requests

def findChampionName(championID):
    url = 'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/champion.json'
    r = requests.get(url)
    json_obj = r.json()
    data = json_obj['data']
    for name, attributes in data.items():
        if attributes['key'] == str(championID):
            return name

print(findChampionName(142))  # None
print(findChampionName(143))  # 'Zyra'
print(findChampionName(122))  # 'Darius'
print(findChampionName(150))  # 'Gnar'
```